# SQL - Group data with same ID and Date that has been to every Machine but has a different Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query that will group data by CT ID and Date that have all 3 MachineID's (1, 10, and 20) and at least one different Sawing Pattern Name.

This Image shows a highlighted example of the data I'm trying to get back and the code i'm currently using

[image: my code]

I'm trying to only show data similar to the highlighted rows in the image (CT ID 501573833) and exclude the data in the rows around it where the Sawing Pattern Name is the same at all 3 MachineID's.

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I suffer a lot from images, can't even comment "please please don't post code and sample data as images". I quit :)

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Your description suggests `group by` and `having`.  The conditions you describe can all go in the `having` clause:

```
select ct_id, date
from t
group by ct_id, date
having sum(case when machineid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when machineid = 10 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when machineid = 20 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       min(sawing_pattern_name) <> max(sawing_pattern_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that an [EXISTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql) could be useful here.

```
SELECT 
[CT ID], 
[MachineID], 
[Sawing Pattern name], 
[Time], 
CAST([Time] AS DATE) AS [Date]
FROM [DataCollector].[dbo].[Maxicut] t
WHERE EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM [DataCollector].[dbo].[Maxicut] d
  WHERE d.[CT ID] = t.[CT ID]
    AND CAST(d.[Time] AS DATE) = CAST(t.[Time] AS DATE)
    AND d.[MachineID] != t.[MachineID]
    AND REPLACE(d.[Sawing Pattern name],',','') != REPLACE(t.[Sawing Pattern name],',','')
);
```